# getting key of observable in knockout js with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Sorry,

If this question has been asked prior, I searched a lot but coudn't get what I need

I have textarea

```
        <textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: quote" name="quote" id="textarea1" required placeholder="Dummy placeholder" rows="4"></textarea>
```

I am not very good in knockout.js and would like to seek your help,

Is there any function in knockout.js which help to get the key (In above case 'quote' , "value: quote") by using the id of the DOM element

Comment: What do you mean by key? Do you want to get the value of the quote?

Comment: @dotnetom I want to get the key ie 'quote' from "value : quote"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about knockout, but using jquery you can access data-attributes like bellow.

```
$('#textarea1').data('bind') // it will return string "value:quote"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/63/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but I think that you need one of `ko.dataFor` or `ko.contextFor`.

In your case you can get data for given element by:

```
var data = ko.dataFor(document.getElementByID('textarea1'))
```

or

```
var context = ko.contextFor(document.getElementByID('textarea1'))
```

If you use `ko.dataFor` you can access `quote` observable by `data.quote`. By using `ko.contextFor` you have object with following attributes: `$parents`, `$root`, `ko`, `$rawData` and `$data`. The `$data` attribute in the context is the same object returned by `ko.dataFor`.